# Time machine says "Disk Full" even though 250GB is still available

Tags: macos, time-machine, apfs, macos-monterey

I have a 5TB external drive, freshly made into a Time Machine backup disk (formatted as APFS). The data I need to backup is about 4.8TB, which should fit fine, and in the past has worked fine on Mojave with a TMB disk formatted MacOS Extended Journaled.

What I’ve noticed is that it will back everything up, but will stop and give a disk full error when the available space reaches 250GB. It won’t budge beyond this, unless I exclude files. Then it will dutifully back up, but if there is 260GB free and I unexclude 30GB of files. it will dutifully back up until 250GB is free and then stop with the disk space error.

So it looks like Time Machine won’t fill up the disk beyond 95% full (4750GB/5TB). This maybe makes sense for SSDs, where reserving 5% as empty space can extend the disk life. But for a regular hard disk it doesn’t help at all, and stops me from making a full backup :/

Is there a way to stop Time Machine from declaring disk full as soon as the 5% free space mark (250GB / 5TB) is hit?

Comment: Time Machine has always been like one of those electronic devices that says "No user-serviceable parts inside" ;) I'd be tempted to have a look at Carbon Copy Cloner instead. If you're filling 4.8 of 5TB, you don't have a lot of room for incremental updates, but if this is going to be relatively static, CCC might just do a better job than TM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has gone away with Monterey 12.3 (was still reproducible through to 12.2).